# "extract string resource" option not found in Android Studio 4.0

Tags: android-studio, flutter, localization

I am getting these  3 options but not getting "extract string resource" option.

I am trying to implement localisation.
I did try to disable and enable the options from :
Help -> Find Action - > search "Extract string resource" and Enable it.

Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is necessary to install Flutter Intl plugin in order to get this functionality.

See [Flutter Intl page](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13666-flutter-intl/) for how to set this up, it is quite straightforward.